# Return value of a function in C

Tags: c, stack, return, return-value, return-type

I tried writing some code to check if the paranthesis in an expression are balances using the below function. Can someone help me understand why the below function is returning 1 in case of a balanced expression when it's not specified anywhere to return 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    char* array;
};

struct Stack* createStack (unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc (sizeof(struct Stack));
    if(!stack)
        return NULL;

stack->top = -1;
stack->capacity = capacity;
stack->array = (char*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));

if (!stack->array)
    return NULL;
return stack;
}

int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return (stack->top == -1);
}
void push(struct Stack* stack, char op)
{
    stack->top++;
    stack->array[stack->top] = op;

}

int pop(struct Stack* stack)
{

    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        return (stack->array[stack->top--]);
    return '$';
}

int isMatchingPair(char char1 , char char2)
{
    if (char1 == '(' && char2 == ')')
        return 1;
    else if (char1 == '[' && char2 == ']')
        return 1;
    else if (char1 == '{' && char2 == '}')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int paranthesesMatch(char* exp)
{
    int i;
    struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
    for(i = 0; exp[i]; i++)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '[' || exp[i] == '{')
        push(stack , exp[i]);
       if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == ']' || exp[i] == '}')
       {
        if (stack == NULL)
            return 0;
        else if ( !isMatchingPair(pop(stack), exp[i]) )
           return 0;

       }
    }
}

int main()
{
  char exp[100] = "{()}[)";
  printf(" %d\n", paranthesesMatch(exp));
  if (paranthesesMatch(exp) == 1)
    printf("Balanced \n");
  else
    printf("Not Balanced \n");  
   return 0;
}
```

Edit: Added the full code.

Comment: By a balanced expression, did you mean all opened braces are closed?

Comment: @sjsam: Yes. That's what I meant

Comment: This can return 0 not 1. I am at a loss.

Comment: 1 is not returned as a legitimate value.

Comment: Show full code including main function and headers and how are you getting 1.

Comment: @Shiv: Added the full code

Comment: @sank Thanks. you will have your answer as someone will give it. I will look at it a bit later.

Comment: Google "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the below function is returning 1 in case of a balanced expression when it's not specified anywhere to return 1.

Your function has branches of code that do not return a value at all. Specifically, when the loop reaches the end, your function does not specify what to return. In situations like that using function's return value is undefined behavior: whatever the function appears to "return" is a junk left-over value that could be different on different computers, or even on the same computer when you run the program multiple times.

As far as the function itself goes, the `NULL` check for a stack is probably incorrect, unless the code deletes the `stack` once it's empty (which would be a rather poor decision). In addition, the code has a memory leak, because `stack` is never freed. It also over-allocates `stack->array` content by a factor of `sizeof(int)` (4 on many computers these days):

```
stack->array = (char*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
stack->array = malloc(stack->capacity);
```

because you make a stack of `char`s, not a stack of `int`s.

Finally, there is no need to allocate `stack` dynamically. Allocate an array of `char`s, and make a "stack pointer" or stack index to point at the beginning of your stack. Increment and decrement the pointer/index when you push/pop elements onto the stack. If you use a variable-length array, you wouldn't need to clean up dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: .: ooops..sorry... yes exactly.

Comment: Hi, NULL check for a stack is to check if there's any opening braces previously pushed into the stack. There should be an opening bracket pushed into the stack for each closing bracket in an expression.

Comment: @sank Then it should be a call to `isEmpty(stack)`, not `stack == NULL`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Noted. Changed that line of my code.

Comment: @sank That by itself is not enough to fix the problem, though. You need to add a check for the stack to be empty at the end of the loop; if it's not empty, your code should return zero; otherwise, it should return `1`. Also your code cannot do an early return, because it needs to free the stack. Make a variable for return value, say, `int ret`, and set it to zero or one in the body of your code. Instead of returning, break the loop. Be careful not to set `ret` to `1` after it's been set to zero. Free the stack, then return `ret`.

Answer (score 5):

Your function returning `1` is the result of undefined behavior. The compiler is free to do whatever it desires, because not all execution paths in your function yield a return statement.

The reason it *may* appear to work is that the caller (that is unaware that the function finished without a return statement), tries to access the returned value (which may be in a designated register). And your function modifies said register before returning to the caller.

Bumping up your warning levels when building, will produce a diagnostic about it ([like so](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/425dc97ce2916823)). You should consider promoting that particular warning to an error, since omitting a return statement can result in sinister and hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Ah as reference to this remember this..
Flowing off the end of a function is same as a return with no expression. In either of this case, the return value is undefined.